# Short website link for all post

Tags: links

I have web site and we need to short link of any post from

> www.thearoundtheworld.info/poas-name-title

to

> www.at.li/kfd

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the easiest way to create shortlink is by using [Jetpack Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) developed by Automatic guys.

This plugin comes with a lot of modules one of them is `wp.me` shortlink, which will give you the ability to create shortlink for any page/post/custom post in your site.

it will be like `http://wp.me/QhtyJu`, but if you want to use any other shortlink service `bit.ly` or `j.mp` you can use [WP Bitly](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-bitly/)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Place read my post again, I need to short link to (www.at.li) not use wp.me or bit.ly, I need to custom link

Comment: First of all as per `WHOIS` data [www.at.li](http://whois.domaintools.com/at.li) domain is unregistered, second of all, you you own the domain, you can easily add it to bit.ly to create your shortlink as `www.at.li/dsdfsarf`. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are looking how to add your custom domain name in bit.ly, you can [check here](http://support.bitly.com/knowledgebase/articles/76741-how-do-i-set-up-a-branded-short-domain)

Answer (score 0):

This is not interest in Wordpress. You can create different different script.
It must has database and in this database, your posts id/slug return random short strings.

Example:

> Post name: Fruits
>
> Slug: fruits
>
> Permalink: localhost/fruits.html

Your script must find rand string and its mean slug and return.
And redirect to same as your Permalink.

Comment: Place read my post again, I need to short link to (www.at.li) not use wp.me or bit.ly, I need to custom link